# Where does undefined comes from?

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
var a = {
   eat: function () {
       console.log('aa')
   }
}
var b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b.eat());
```

The output of that lines in Chrome is following

> aa  script.js:3 
>   undefined script.js:7

First line is obvious, but where does second line of output, "undefined", comes from ?

Comment: Where does undefined *not* come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to log the return value of the `eat` method, but it does not have a return statement so an undefined value is logged instead.

Answer (score 0):

while b.eat() function is executing its log the the value "aa" but its has nothing to return so returning `undefined`

try to return something from function to avoid `undefined`